# YouTube Restricted Playback Issue

Tags: javascript, php, youtube, youtube-api

I'm unable to embed certain YT videos.

The error I'm receiving is as follows:

The video contains content from VEVO, who has blocked it from display on this website.

I do not believe it's simply restricting embeds as the video I'm testing with shows up, embeded on other sites such as:

http://youtubeonrepeat.com/watch/?v=fk4BbF7B29w

I'm using the YouTube IFRAME API to load the video and I've attempted to embed the video using playervars such as "origin" and "enablejsapi" to no avail.

Example:

```
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'fk4BbF7B29w',
      playerVars: {
        'origin': 'https://api.specivid.com',
        'enablejsapi' : 1
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
```

Am I just SOL or am I missing something?

The page I am testing the embed on is:
https://api.specivid.com/test.php

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would help if you read [Understand Playback Restrictions](https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions_28.html).

> With enhanced content controls comes increased complexity. The only
>   foolproof way to determine if a user has access to watch a video is to
>   ask them to try watching it. So, if you’re writing an application and
>   you’d like to prevent users from seeing videos that they don’t have
>   the ability to watch, here are a list of things to check:

1. `yt:accessControl`

Videos that are available for embedding on third-party applications will have the following:

```
<yt:accesscontrol action='embed' permission='allowed' />
```

If you’d like to only search for videos that are embeddable, add `format=5` to your query.
Just as a video can be embeddable or not, it can also be syndicatable or not:

```
<yt:accesscontrol action='syndicate' permission='allowed' />
```

A video that is embeddable but not syndicatable will play on YouTube.com or on other sites that embed the YouTube player, but may not play on devices such as mobile phones or TVs. If you’d like to learn more about retrieving videos suitable for playback on mobile devices, see the developer’s guide.

2. Geo Restrictions

Some videos may be restricted in certain countries. This restriction applies to where the viewer is located, not where your third-party server is located. For instance, if a video is blocked in the US, it will have the following:

```
<media:restriction type='country'
  relationship='deny'>US</media:restriction>
```

When you make a query, you can add a restriction parameter to filter videos that will not be playable by a client with a specific IP or from a specific country.

3. `yt:state`

It’s also important to check the `yt:state` of the video in the API response. Even if `yt:accessControl` indicates that syndication is allowed, `yt:state` might override it. For example, a video that has limited syndication would have the following:

```
<app:control>
  <yt:state name='restricted' reasoncode='limitedSyndication'>
    Syndication of this video was restricted by its owner.
  </yt:state>
</app:control>
```

You might also see the message, “Syndication of this video was restricted by the content owner.” Hence, even if the uploader allows syndication, the content owner could override that and disallow syndication. For example, this could happen if someone uploads a video that contains a soundtrack that is owned by another content owner.

4. Rentals

Some YouTube videos are rentals. You can tell that they are rentals because they have a `media:price` tag:

```
<media:price type='rent' price='1.99' currency='USD' yt:duration='PT2592000S' />
```

Note that the `media:price` tag is only included in the response if you use a developer key in the query. If you are building a non-browser based YouTube application where it would be impossible for the user to rent a video, you might want to filter out the rentals. You can do that by passing the parameter `paid-content=false`.

5. Other Restrictions not Currently Exposed via the API

There are even more subtle restrictions that occasionally come into play. Not all of these are currently queryable via the API. For instance, some videos are only playable on a certain set of domains. As I mentioned above, the only foolproof way to know if a user has access to watch a video is to have them try watching it.

Also, check the Youtube guide on [Embed a player using an <iframe> tag](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters).

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the very thorough response.